Chowla's theorem on class number of real quadratic field
Let $p\equiv1\bmod 4$ be a prime number and $h$
the class number of real quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$, $\epsilon=\frac{t+u\sqrt{p}}{2}$ its fundamental unit. In this paper https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.47.6.878(Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 47 (1961), 878.) Chowla proves the following result
$$h\equiv1\bmod 4\Longleftrightarrow\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv-\frac{t}{2}\bmod p$$
or
$$\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv(-1)^{\frac{h+1}{2}}\cdot\frac{t}{2}\bmod p.$$
In the proof, his first show that
$$\sqrt{p}\cdot\epsilon^{h}=\prod\limits_{\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=-1}(1-\zeta^n)$$
where the product is over all the quadratic non-residue modulo $p$. This identity can be deduced by Dirichlet's class number formula.
Let $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$ be the $p$-th primitive root of unit. We know that
$$p\mathbb Z[\zeta]=(1-\zeta)^{p-1},\quad \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta).$$
Then Chowla Claim that in the ring $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$,
$$\prod\limits_{\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=-1}(1-\zeta^n)\equiv
\left(\prod\limits_{\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=-1}n\right)(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\bmod (1-\zeta)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv\epsilon^{-h}\cdot(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\bmod(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}.$$
From this, he can deduce his theorem.
I kown how to prove the first congruence identity. In fact we have that
$$\frac{1-\zeta^k}{1-\zeta}=1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\cdots+\zeta^{k-1}\equiv k\bmod (1-\zeta)\Longrightarrow
1-\zeta^k\equiv k(1-\zeta)\bmod (1-\zeta)^2.$$
My Question: How to prove the second congruence identity, I mean how to prove
$$\sqrt{p}\equiv\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\cdot(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\bmod(1-\zeta)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}.$$

Note that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta^n)=\Phi_p(1)=p,
$$
where $\Phi_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ is the cyclotomic polynomial. Next, $1-\zeta^{p-n}=-\zeta^{-n}(1-\zeta^n)$, hence we have
$$
p=\prod_{n=1}^{(p-1)/2} (1-\zeta^n)^2(-\zeta^{-n}),
$$
therefore
$$
\left(\prod_{n=1}^{(p-1)/2}(1-\zeta^n)\right)^2=p\zeta^{(p^2-1)/
8},
$$
because $1+2+\cdots+(p-1)/2=\frac{p^2-1}{8}$. Also, $1-\zeta^n=-2i \zeta^{n/2}\sin\frac{\pi n}{p}$, hence the product in LHS above is equal to
$$
(-i)^{(p-1)/2}\zeta^{(p^2-1)/16}\sqrt{p}. 
$$
Let $\eta=\sqrt{\zeta}$ be a primitive $2p$-th root of unity. Then $(-i)^{(p-1)/2}=(-1)^{(p-1)/4}=\eta^{p(p-1)/4}$. Note now that $p(p-1)/4+(p^2-1)/8=(p-1)(3p+1)/8$ is an even number, so
$$
(-i)^{(p-1)/2}\zeta^{(p^2-1)/16}=\eta^{(p-1)(3p+1)/8}=\zeta^k\equiv 1\pmod {1-\zeta}
$$
Hence
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{(p-1)/2}(1-\zeta^n)=\zeta^k \sqrt{p}.
$$
Dividing both sides by $\zeta^k(1-\zeta)^{(p-1)/2}$ and using the observation $\frac{1-\zeta^n}{1-\zeta}\equiv n\pmod {1-\zeta}$ stated in the question, we see that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{p}}{(1-\zeta)^{(p-1)/2}}\equiv \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \pmod {1-\zeta},
$$
as needed.
